# Screen Time countdown for specific website/app starts as soon as I open my Mac

Tags: safari, catalina, screen-time

I've set up Screen Time limits for YouTube and a handful of other apps on my iOS devices, and those sync over to my Mac. On Catalina, the YouTube app limit automatically also applies to http://youtube.com.

[image: Screen Time preferences]

However, that countdown appears to start as soon as I start my Mac, or perhaps when I open Safari. I did *not* visit YouTube on either my iOS devices nor my Mac yet, and it's already counted and hour and a half of usage, closely coinciding with the length I had my Mac started for.

Is this just buggy, or is there anything I can do to make it count *only* the length of time I actually visit the YouTube website?

Comment: Could be cached content, restart Safari by holding down shift and clicking on the dock icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have sorted itself out with the latest update. Not sure whether there was an unmentioned bug fix in there, some caches or something got cleaned out during the installation, or it was just the reboot.